# Como converter data.frame para list?

Tags: r

Carreguei meus dados utilizando

```
taxadados<-read.csv2("ComponentesPrincipaisTeste.csv",header=TRUE)


TAXA         Taxa.1   Taxa.2  Taxa.3 Taxa.4  Taxa.5 Taxa.6   Taxa.7 Taxa.8
09/04/2013  32.7188   8.8350 13.0662 9.0114  8.7003 8.9924  76.7003 9.2542
10/04/2013  376.7003  8.8170 67.0762 8.9842  8.9924 9.0395   8.9924 9.2247
11/04/2013  67.9924   8.8589 13.0656 9.0357 14.3199 8.9912 667.3199 9.2815
```

Eles vieram, obviamente, como Data.Frame.

Como faço para convertê-los para o formato "list"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `as.list`.

Por exemplo:

```
df <- read.table(text = "TAXA  Taxa.1  Taxa.2  Taxa.3 Taxa.4  Taxa.5 Taxa.6  Taxa.7 Taxa.8
09/04/2013  32.7188  8.8350 13.0662 9.0114  8.7003 8.9924  76.7003 9.2542
10/04/2013  376.7003  8.8170 67.0762 8.9842  8.9924 9.0395  8.9924 9.2247
11/04/2013  67.9924  8.8589 13.0656 9.0357 14.3199 8.9912 667.3199 9.2815", header = TRUE)

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ TAXA  : Factor w/ 3 levels "09/04/2013","10/04/2013",..: 1 2 3
 $ Taxa.1: num  32.7 376.7 68
 $ Taxa.2: num  8.84 8.82 8.86
 $ Taxa.3: num  13.1 67.1 13.1
 $ Taxa.4: num  9.01 8.98 9.04
 $ Taxa.5: num  8.7 8.99 14.32
 $ Taxa.6: num  8.99 9.04 8.99
 $ Taxa.7: num  76.7 8.99 667.32
 $ Taxa.8: num  9.25 9.22 9.28
```

Transformando em lista:

```
lista <- as.list(df)
str(lista)
List of 9
 $ TAXA  : Factor w/ 3 levels "09/04/2013","10/04/2013",..: 1 2 3
 $ Taxa.1: num [1:3] 32.7 376.7 68
 $ Taxa.2: num [1:3] 8.84 8.82 8.86
 $ Taxa.3: num [1:3] 13.1 67.1 13.1
 $ Taxa.4: num [1:3] 9.01 8.98 9.04
 $ Taxa.5: num [1:3] 8.7 8.99 14.32
 $ Taxa.6: num [1:3] 8.99 9.04 8.99
 $ Taxa.7: num [1:3] 76.7 8.99 667.32
 $ Taxa.8: num [1:3] 9.25 9.22 9.28
```

Em geral, no `R`, quando você quer converter um objeto em outro você vai utilizar uma função do tipo `as.objeto`.

Vale lembrar, no entanto, que um `data.frame` já é uma lista, apenas com atributos a mais. Então ao fazer `as.list` você apenas está retirando estes atributos (como `row.names`).

```
is.list(df)
TRUE
```

Comment: estou tentando calcular uma Cubic Spline pela função         estim_cs(bonddata, group, matrange="all", rse=TRUE)   onde "bonddata" esta no formato "List". Consegui transformar em Lis mas quando calculo a função a resposta é:  no applicable method for 'estim_cs' applied to an object of class "list".

Comment: Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: @DiogoBastos, seria melhor você fazer outra pergunta então, colocando exatamente o pacote que você está usando etc.

Comment: @DiogoBastos Como o Carlos explicou, uma data.frame já é uma lista. Não me recordo de ver algum caso que você precise fazer este tipo de transformação, listas "normais" são úteis quando os elementos são de tamanhos ou profundidades diferentes.